# クローズ理由の例示テキストをスタック・オーバーフローに適合する内容へ変更するべきか？

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

質問のクローズ理由の中に「その他」という項目があり、クローズに投票した理由を自由に記述出来ます。ここのテキストボックスには例示テキストが書かれており、プレースホルダに以下のような文章が設定されています:

> **(原文)**: [ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13425)
> E.g. Looks like this question is about typesetting systems and would be a good fit for TeX-LaTex Stack Exchange.
>
> ---
>
> **(翻訳)**
> 例. 組版システムに関する質問は Tex-LaTex Stack Exchange がより適切だと思います。

[image: Other という見出しの下のフォームに英文がプレースホルダとして書かれている]

スタック・オーバーフローでは Stack Overflow よりも広い範囲をオントピックとして扱っており、日本語版の Stack Exchange のサイトはスタック・オーバーフローのみであるため、組版システムに関する質問であることが**クローズの理由として妥当ではない**可能性があります。

そこで質問です。この文字列を変更し、よりスタック・オーバーフローに適合した内容にするべきでしょうか？それとも、現状のまま使用するべきでしょうか？また、もし文字列を変更する場合、どういった内容にすると良いと思いますか？

Comment: +1: 適切でないことには賛成です。処置については、そもそもこの string が実際に使われているものかどうかを調べるところからかな、と思っています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> コメントありがとうございます。確かに、質問文に文章で書くだけでは実際の場所がわかりづらいですね。スクリーンショットも追加しました。

Comment: なるほど、既に使われている string だったんですね、すいません確認不足でした……。こんなところに……。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 既に使われていたというか、クローズダイアログの見直し(更新)に伴って追加された文字列だと思われます。

Comment: @cubick はい、それは認識していたのですが、更新が既にデプロイされていたのを知りませんでした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ご提案いただいた和訳](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3368/14055)を [Traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13425) に入力し、2020年後半頃にはサイトに反映されていたようです。しかしその後、新しい [string](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13430) に置き換わってしまったため、現在は以下のように表示されております。

> 私はこの質問にクローズ票を投票します。なぜなら...

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
タグの付け替えが遅くなり申し訳ありません‍♀️。

Answer (score 4):

TeX/LaTeX を使った組版プログラムに関する質問は日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにおいてはオントピックなので、文章の意味から変えることに賛成です。内容的にここにしか使われていない string だと思ってよさそうなので、大胆に意訳してしまいたいです。

この string は見た感じ、既にリストされているサイトでは無いサイトへの migrate が適切である、というクローズ理由を例に挙げて書こうとしているようです。というわけで他に考えられる migrate 先として、[Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) はどうでしょうか。

このような感じに訳すのを想定しています：

> 例：この質問は日本語の細かい使い方について聞いており、Japanese Language Stack Exchange の方が適切そうです。

ひとつ気になる点としては Japanese Language Stack Exchange は英語で運営されているサイトなので、日本語の質問をそのまま migrate してしまうと向こうで close されてしまう危険性があることくらいでしょうか。まあ例なのでやや多めに見るということで……。